# Cannot find type definition file for 'leaflet'

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, leaflet

running `ionic codrova run android` and i'm getting back this error:

```
typescript error
Cannot find type definition file for 'leaflet'.

TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of null
    at Object.escapeHtml (C:\Users\mes\Desktop\Mobile-DevM\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\util\helpers.js:253:10)
    at generateCodeBlock (C:\Users\mes\Desktop\Mobile-DevM\node_modules\@ionic\app-scripts\dist\logger\logger-diagnostics.js:187:77)
......
```

thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can try installing [@types/leaflet](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet) if you have not done yet.

`npm install @types/leaflet`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this did not work for me.